# Simpler version of dogbone space construction

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

In "The cartesian product of a certain nonmanifold and a line is $E^4$" (R.H. Bing, *Annals of Mathematics* series 2 vol **70** 1959 pp. 399–412) Bing constructs a nonmanifold, $B$, such that $B\times \Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.

> Is there a space $X$, not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, such that $X\times \Bbb R $ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: No, such spaces do not exist. You can prove it yourself by thinking about Hanno's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322411/topological-characterization-of-the-closed-interval-0-1/322519#322519).