# Is $X\simeq [0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Suppose that $X$ is a metric continuum irreducible between two points $p$ and $q$.

Suppose further that whenever $U$ is a connected open set missing $p$ and $q$, we have $X\setminus U$ has two connected components, one containing $p$ and the other containing $q$.

Is $X$ necessarily equal to (homeomorphic to) $[0,1]$?

EDIT: I don't have much context to add.  I came up with this question while trying to solve a very different problem. Honestly I have to clue if the answer is yes or no, though if the answer is yes it would be useful to me.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322411/topological-characterization-of-the-closed-interval-0-1/322519#322519

Comment: @studiosus thanks, let me think about why every point other than $p$ and $q$ is a cut point...

Comment: It’s shocking that there are four votes to close.

Comment: Yes, its quite ridiculous to close this question.

Comment: Please improve this post by adding additional context. Questions which only pose a problem are often put on hold.

Comment: Here it seems that an irreducible Continuum which is locally connected is homeomorphic to an interval. Does your further hypothesis implies local connectedness? https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Continuum